# javascript works on jsFiddle, but not on live server

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I am trying to make a Word Doc form into an online form so that we can guarantee the results and for the convenience of our users. When I test the javascript out on jsfiddle it works perfect, but when I upload it to our server and access it, it doesn't work.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4avkn9q/8/

And here's the code behind the page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BUILDER Building Add Request (DHA)</title>

        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <style>
        function Org1Pick() {
            var Org1 = document.getElementById("OrgDHA").value;
            document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("OrgChoice").innerHTML = Org1+" selected";
            switch (Org1) {
                case "AFMS":
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").list = "ORG-DHA-AFMS";
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").placeholder = "DHA-AFMS";
                    break;
                case "BUMED":
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").list = "ORG-DHA-BUMED";
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").placeholder = "DHA-BUMED";
                    break;
                case "MEDCOM":
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").list = "ORG-DHA-MEDCOM";
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").placeholder = "DHA-MEDCOM";
                    break;
                case "NCR":
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").list = "ORG-DHA-NCR";
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").placeholder = "DHA-NCR";
                    break;
                default:
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("OrgAFMS").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("OrgBUMED").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("OrgMEDCOM").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("OrgNCR").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
        </style>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <style>
            .form_desc {
                text-align: right;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            .form_input {
                text-align: left;
                vertical-align: top;
                font-style: italic;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <input type="text" list="ORG-DHA" id="OrgDHA" placeholder="Select an Organization" onchange="Org1Pick()" />
            <input type="text" list="ORG-DHA" id="OrgDHA2" placeholder="" onchange="Org2Pick()" style="visibility:hidden" />
            <div id="OrgChoice" >No Organization(s) seleceted.</div>
        </div>

        <!-- ORG datalists -->
        <datalist id="ORG-DHA">
            <option value="AFMS">
            <option value="BUMED">
            <option value="MEDCOM">
            <option value="NCR">
        </datalist>
        <datalist id="ORG-DHA-AFMS">
            <option value="ACC">
            <option value="AETC">
            <option value="AFDW">
            <option value="AFGSC">
            <option value="AFMC">
            <option value="AFSOC">
            <option value="AFSPC">
            <option value="AMC">
            <option value="PACAF">
            <option value="USAFE">
        </datalist>
        <datalist id="ORG-DHA-BUMED">
            <option value="DET JAX">
            <option value="NME">
            <option value="NMW">
        </datalist>
        <datalist id="ORG-DHA-MEDCOM">
            <option value="ERMC">
            <option value="MRMC">
            <option value="NRMC">
            <option value="PRMC">
            <option value="SRMC">
            <option value="USAPHC">
            <option value="WRMC">
        </datalist>
        <datalist id="ORG-DHA-NCR">
            <option value="UHUHS">
            <option value="WRNMMC Bethesda">
        </datalist>

    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing? I am sure it's something really simple, but I'm just not seeing it.

**UPDATE:** By "not working" I meant that nothing happened once I selected the option from the dropdown menu.

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error? What does the log say? Does something simply not happen?

Comment: You need to define `doesn't work` before we can help you.  Is an error thrown?  Is the output incorrect?  What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: `style ` is used for css, not for javascript

Answer (score 6):

You've put the *script* in a `<style>` element instead of a `<script>` element.

Comment: Ding! Ding! Ding! We have a winner! I knew I was simply overlooking something simple. I don't have enough credibility/reputation to up vote your answer, but that was it.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `<style>` tag with `<script>` tag:

```
<scipt type="text/javascript">
        function Org1Pick() {
            var Org1 = document.getElementById("OrgDHA").value;
            document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("OrgChoice").innerHTML = Org1+" selected";
            switch (Org1) {
                case "AFMS":
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").list = "ORG-DHA-AFMS";
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").placeholder = "DHA-AFMS";
                    break;
                case "BUMED":
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").list = "ORG-DHA-BUMED";
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").placeholder = "DHA-BUMED";
                    break;
                case "MEDCOM":
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").list = "ORG-DHA-MEDCOM";
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").placeholder = "DHA-MEDCOM";
                    break;
                case "NCR":
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").list = "ORG-DHA-NCR";
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").placeholder = "DHA-NCR";
                    break;
                default:
                    alert(Org1);
                    document.getElementById("OrgDHA2").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("OrgAFMS").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("OrgBUMED").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("OrgMEDCOM").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("OrgNCR").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple I was overlooking.